# telling GNU MAKE to use a user provided directory for object files creation

Tags: compilation, makefile

I want to build a file with GNU make on a machine which I have write permission only to the tmp directory.

When I try to build I get a permission error because MAKE is trying to put the object file in the build directory which I have no write permissions for.

is it possible to provide make a specific directory where to put the object files ?

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: That's not really a make decision. That depends on how the rules are written.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to provide make a specific directory where to put the object files ?

If the makefile does not allow specifying a build directory you can copy (or symlink if possible) the sources into the destination directory and build there.

Autoconf-based projects normally allow this kind of usage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your make rules are coming from.

Usually, rules are written to be location independent: they are written such that whether the `make` command will work regardless of where the source files are.  This is true for the built-in rules, but also for the rules in most `Makefile`s, if you got any.

In that case, all you need to do is copy or move everything into `/tmp` and run `make` there.

However, if you generated your `Makefile`s with a tool (e.g. a `./configure` script, as used by [GNU autoconf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoconf)), the generation process may have introduced absolute paths, so you may need to redo the generation step(s) after copying everything to `/tmp`.